# when click on sub li the click function is calling twice. how can i solve it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, cordova

I create the menu dynamically in `jquery`. I created a parent `ul` and `li` and it works fine. If I appended the `ul` to any of the `li` it's appended but when I click on that child `li` i am not able to get the id for any of child `ul` or `li`. I gave the id to that child `li`. I even tried  to write the click action using `li` id or class that is also not working. Please find the below code.

Can any one please help me?

[image]

From the above image I want to get the id for category1 when I click on that category1.

Html:

```
<ul id="menu"> </ul>
```

Script:

```
$("#menu").on("click", "li", function () {
    $("#menu ul").empty('');
    var html = "<ul class='sub_ul'>";
    var abc = subArrays[$(this).attr('id')];
    for(var i = 0; i < abc.length; i++) {
        if(abc[i] != ' ') {
            html = html + "<li class='sub_first_li' id='sub_" + $(this).attr('id') + "_" + i + "'><a class='sub_first_li' href='#'>" + abc[i] + "</a></li>";
        }
        html = html + "</ul>";
        $(this).append(html);
        $("#menu ul").css({
            'display': 'block'
        });
    });
});
```

Update : 
   Now i am getting the corrected li id but when i click on any li(category1) the function
   will fire twice. What i need to do to make a call it once? Can any one please help me..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you generating `li` dynamically.

You need to use [**Event Delegation**](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/). You have to use [**.on()**](http://api.jquery.com/on/) using delegated-events approach.

i.e. (General example)

```
$(document).on('event','selector',callback_function)
```

For you

```
$("#menu").on('click', "li", function(){
    //Your code
});
```

Event handlers are bound only to the currently selected elements; they must exist on the page at the time your code makes the event binding call.

> The delegated events have the advantage that they can process events from descendant elements that are added to the document at a later time. By picking an element that is guaranteed to be present at the time the delegated event handler is attached, we can use delegated events to bind the click event to dynamically created elements and also to avoid the need to frequently attach and remove event handlers.

Comment: it's working fine. when i click on child li i m getting id but $("#menu").on('click', "li", function() this is function is calling two times. How to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

This may be a CSS selector issue. The first thing that comes to mind is that `#menu li` is a *descendant* selector. It selects all *li*'s anywhere under the *#menu*. Likewise, `#menu ul` selects both *ul*'s underneath #menu.

Therefore, your anonymous function is firing every time you click "category1". Try using the child selector: `#menu > ul` and `#menu > ul > li`. I'm curious to see if that solves your problem.

Comment: Also, Satpal's answer is critical to attach event handlers to elements that are not present in the DOM at the time the handler is attached.